# std::unordered_map<> bucket_count() after default rehash

Tags: c++, std, unordered-map

If i keep adding values to an unordered_map then every time the number of elements exceeds the bucket_count() (assuming max_load_factor = 1) rehashing takes place.

What I am very confused about is the bucket size after rehashing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
int main() {
   std::unordered_map<size_t, size_t> mp;

   for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
      mp[i] = i;
      std::cout << " count: " << mp.bucket_count() << std::endl;
   }
}
```

This outputs 3 7 17 37 79 167 337 709 1493

I have noticed that the bucket size is prime and approximately doubles. However it is not the closest prime to the next power of 2 either.

What is the methodology behind this bucket size increase.
I was surprised or stupid enough that I couldn't find anything about it in standard references such as cplusplus.com

Comment: It's most likely implementation defined. The implementations used by g++ and clang are open source, I believe.

Comment: Standard mandates nothing there. Perhaps usage of primes makes hash algorithms that guarantee highly different bit patterns in hash for only slightly different objects unneeded.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: This is very surprising. These maps are commonly known to have constant time insertion. If the standard mandates nothing than insertion could as well trigger a rehash after each and every insertion, i.e. make it a linear time operation.

Comment: @FloRyan If you are worried then reserve(). In my experience the std::unordered_maps of different implementations are relatively similar in performance. Bigger surprise can be for example with std::deque whose chunk size does differ between implementations and performance can noticeably differ but there are no way to regulate size of chunks nor does it have ways to reserve().

Answer (score 1):

The bucket sizes after rehashing will be compiler specific. The specific numbers you are seeing can be found by taking the current bucket size, multiplying by 2, and then taking the nearest prime larger than that value from the __prime_list array here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/5bea0e90e58d971cf3e67f784a116d81a20b927a/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/shared/hashtable-aux.cc