# hash function for a 64-bit OS/compile, for an object that's really just a 4-byte int

Tags: c++11, hashcode

I have a class named Foo that is privately nothing more than 4-byte int.  If I return its value as an 8-byte size_t, am I going to be screwing up `unordered_map<>` or anything else?  I could fill all bits with something like `return foo + foo << 32;`.  Would that be better, or would it be worse as all hashes are now multiples of 0x100000001?  Or how about `return ~foo + foo << 32;` which would use all 64 bits and also not have a common factor?

```
namespace std {
  template<> struct hash<MyNamespace::Foo> {
    typedef size_t result_type;
    typedef MyNamespace::Foo argument_tupe;
    size_t operator() (const MyNamespace::Foo& f ) const { return (size_t) f.u32InternalValue; }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An incremental `uint32_t` key converted to `uint64_t` works well**

`unordered_map` will reserve space for the hash-table incrementally.

The less significant bits of the key is used to determine the bucket position, in an example for 4 entries/buckets, the less significant 2 bits are used.
Elements with a key giving the same bucket (multiple of the number of buckets) are chained in a linked list. This carry the concept of load-factor.

```
// 4 Buckets example

******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******XX

bucket 00 would contains keys like {0, 256, 200000 ...}
bucket 01 would contains keys like {1, 513, 4008001 ...}
bucket 10 would contains keys like {2, 130, 10002 ...}
bucket 11 would contains keys like {3, 259, 1027, 20003, ...}
```

If you try to save an additional values in a bucket, and it load factor goes over the limit, the table is resized (e.g. you try to save a 5th element in a 4-bucket table with load_factor=1.0).

Consequently:

Having a `uint32_t` or a `uint64_t` key will have little impact until you reach 2^32-elements hash-table.

> Would that be better, or would it be worse as all hashes are now multiples of 0x100000001?

This will have no impact until you reach 32-bits overflow (2^32) hash-table.

Good key conversion between incremental uint32_t and uint64_t:

```
key64 = static_cast<uint64>(key32);
```

Bad key conversion between incremental uint32_t and uint64_t:

```
key64 = static_cast<uint64>(key32)<<32;
```

The best is to keep the keys as even as possible, avoiding hashes with the same factor again and again. E.g. in the code below, keys with all factor 7 would have collision until resized to 16 buckets.

https://onlinegdb.com/r1N7TNySv

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

// Print to std output the internal structure of an unordered_map.
template <typename K, typename T>
void printMapStruct(unordered_map<K, T>& map)
{
    cout << "The map has " << map.bucket_count()<< 
        " buckets and max load factor: " << map.max_load_factor() << endl;
    
    for (size_t i=0; i< map.bucket_count(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "    Bucket " << i << ": ";
        for (auto it=map.begin(i); it!=map.end(i); ++it)
        {
            cout << it->first << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// Print the list of bucket sizes by this implementation
void printMapResizes()
{
    cout << "Map bucket counts:"<< endl;
    unordered_map<size_t, size_t> map;
    
    size_t lastBucketSize=0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<1024*1024; ++i)
    {
        if (lastBucketSize!=map.bucket_count())
        {
            cout << map.bucket_count() << " ";
            lastBucketSize = map.bucket_count();
        }
        map.emplace(i,i);
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    unordered_map<size_t,size_t> map;
    
    printMapStruct(map);
    
    map.emplace(0,0);
    map.emplace(1,1);
    printMapStruct(map);
    
    map.emplace(72,72);
    map.emplace(17,17);
    printMapStruct(map);
    
    map.emplace(7,7);
    map.emplace(14,14);
    printMapStruct(map);
    
    printMapResizes();

    return 0;
}
```

Note over the bucket count:

In the above example, the bucket count is as follow:

> 1 3 7 17 37 79 167 337 709 1493 3209 6427 12983 26267 53201 107897 218971 444487 902483 1832561

This seems to purposely follow a series of prime numbers (minimizing collisions). I am not aware of the function behind.

[std::unordered_map<> bucket_count() after default rehash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60503214/stdunordered-map-bucket-count-after-default-rehash)

Comment: Thx Adrian but I don't see if this answers my first question.  Is a hash key of 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx going to work well, especially when x is going to be a low number counting from 1?

Comment: I fixed the explanation, added an example and removed some poor assumptions.

Comment: *I am not aware of the function behind.* -- It looks like they take the next prime more than twice the current prime.  Just a guess, and they surely store it in an array anyway as the algo would take more room to implement than 64 or fewer 8 byte ints...

Comment: I checked, this, but no: 709x2=1418, next is 1423